# dot of bold symbol does not appear in ACM format

Tags: pdftex, acmart

I am writing the following equation to put a dot on a bold symbol math character but the dot does not show up; however, this works in the IEEEtran format.

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

%
% defining the \BibTeX command - from Oren Patashnik's original BibTeX documentation.
\def\BibTeX{{\rm B\kern-.05em{\sc i\kern-.025em b}\kern-.08emT\kern-.1667em\lower.7ex\hbox{E}\kern-.125emX}}

% Rights management information. 
% This information is sent to you when you complete the rights form.
% These commands have SAMPLE values in them; it is your responsibility as an author to replace
% the commands and values with those provided to you when you complete the rights form.
%
% These commands are for a PROCEEDINGS abstract or paper.
\copyrightyear{2019}
\acmYear{2019}
\setcopyright{acmlicensed}
\acmConference[CPS-SR '19]{CPS-SR '19: Cyber-Physical Systems and Internet-of-Things Week}{April 15--19, 2019}{Montreal, Canada}
\acmBooktitle{CPS-SR '19: 2$^\text{nd}$ Workshop on Cyber-Physical Systems Security and Resilience, April 15--19, 2019, Montreal, Canada}
\acmPrice{15.00}
\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}
\acmISBN{978-1-4503-9999-9/18/06}

\usepackage{amsmath, amsfonts, amssymb, color, enumerate, amsthm, graphicx, mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz, subcaption}
\usepackage{color, xcolor, soul, bm}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyphens}{url}\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks   = true, %Colours links instead of ugly boxes
    urlcolor     = blue, %Colour for external hyperlinks
    linkcolor    = blue, %Colour of internal links
    citecolor   = green %Colour of citations
}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newtheorem{assumption}{Assumption}
\newtheorem{proposition}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{lemma}{Lemma}
\newtheorem{remark}{Remark}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\newtheorem{example}{Example}
\usepackage{epsfig} 
\usepackage{psfrag}
\DeclareMathOperator{\diag}{diag}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\newcommand{\JW}[1]{{\color{red}#1}}
\include{user_newcommands}

\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\allowdisplaybreaks

%\newcommand{\ShS}[1]{$\clubsuit$\footnote{SHREYAS: #1}}
%\newcommand{\mathcolorbox}[2]{\colorbox{#1}{$\displaystyle #2$}}

%\def\endtheorem{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\def\endlemma{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\def\endproposition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\def\endexample{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\def\endremark{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}
%\def\enddefinition{\hspace*{\fill}~\IEEEQEDopen\par\endtrivlist\unskip}

%
% These commands are for a JOURNAL article.
%\setcopyright{acmcopyright}
%\acmJournal{TOG}
%\acmYear{2018}\acmVolume{37}\acmNumber{4}\acmArticle{111}\acmMonth{8}
%\acmDOI{10.1145/1122445.1122456}

%
% Submission ID. 
% Use this when submitting an article to a sponsored event. You'll receive a unique submission ID from the organizers
% of the event, and this ID should be used as the parameter to this command.
%\acmSubmissionID{123-A56-BU3}

%
% The majority of ACM publications use numbered citations and references. If you are preparing content for an event
% sponsored by ACM SIGGRAPH, you must use the "author year" style of citations and references. Uncommenting
% the next command will enable that style.
%\citestyle{acmauthoryear}

%
% end of the preamble, start of the body of the document source.
\begin{document}
$\boldsymbol{\tilde{x}} = [\mathbf{\tilde{P}} \quad \mathbf{\dot{\tilde{P}}}]^{\sf T}=[\tilde{p}_1, \tilde{p}_2, \ldots, \tilde{p}_n, \dot{\tilde{p}}_1, \dot{\tilde{p}}_2, \ldots, \dot{\tilde{p}}_n]^{\sf T}$
\end{document}
```

This the result in which the red P does not have a dot on top of it,

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try the following:

```
\documentclass[sigconf]{acmart}

\begin{document}
$
\tilde{\mathbf{x}}
    = [\tilde{\mathbf{P}} \quad \dot{\tilde{\mathbf{P}}}]^\intercal
    = [\tilde{p}_1, \tilde{p}_2, \ldots, \tilde{p}_n,
       \dot{\tilde{p}}_1, \dot{\tilde{p}}_2, \ldots, \dot{\tilde{p}}_n]^\intercal
$

\medskip
or with use of the \verb+\bigl[+ and \verb+\bigr]+ for square brackets 

delimiters (as suggest @egreg in his comment):

\medskip
$
\tilde{\mathbf{x}}
    = \Bigl[\tilde{\mathbf{P}} \quad \dot{\tilde{\mathbf{P}}}\Bigr]^\intercal
    = \Bigl[\tilde{p}_1, \tilde{p}_2, \ldots, \tilde{p}_n,
            \dot{\tilde{p}}_1, \dot{\tilde{p}}_2, \ldots, \dot{\tilde{p}}_n\Bigr]^\intercal
$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Not with `\left` and `\right`, please.

Comment: @egreg, it is convenient ... is not needed to search for right size of `\bigl` or `\Bigl˙, ... :-).  now corrected (but not sure, if i select correct ones, so i left selection to op).

Comment: Delimiters need not cover the whole thing, accents in particular. Possibly `\big` size could do, but in this case, normal size is the best, in my opinion, and `\left`-`\right` produce an awful output.

Comment: @egreg, done :-)